# Правильно ли по смыслу и пунктуации составлено предложение?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, редактура

*Том игриво улыбнулся и приподняв указательным пальцем за подбородок, голову девушки, рассмеялся.*

Comment: Стилистику нужно поправить. (1) Том игриво улыбнулся и рассмеялся. Звучит немного странно. (2) Очень длинный деепричастный оборот (много подробностей в одном месте, так обычно не пишут).  Всю эту фразу надо удачно встроить в контекст. Для этого неплохо посмотреть примеры на ресурсе "Карта слов", например:  https://kartaslov.ru/предложения-со-словосочетанием/приподнять+пальцем+подбородок,   https://kartaslov.ru/предложения-со-словосочетанием/указательный+палец

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сложно сказать, можно ли за подбородок пальчиком приподнять чью-то голову, а за пунктуацию скажу, что перед *головой* (дополнением) запятая совсем не нужна, а перед деепричастным оборотом как раз нужна:

*Том игриво улыбнулся и, приподняв указательным пальцем за подбородок голову девушки, рассмеялся.*

Может быть, так переделать:

*Том игриво улыбнулся и, коснувшись указательным пальцем подбородка девушки, привлёк её внимание и рассмеялся.*